# Supabase Python On Conlict, Ascending

Tags: python, supabase

After reading the supabase-py documentation, I can't find my answer.

I want to use the on_conflict parameter during an insert, but it returns an error.

```
supabase.table("user").upsert([{"id": 5, "name": "John"}], on_conflict="id").execute()
```

Also, this time I want to return elements in descending order using the order parameter. I tried setting the ascending parameter to false without success.

```
supabase.table("user").select("*").order(age, ascending=False).execute()
```

Can you help me with my syntax errors?

Comment: What error are you seeing?